# How to get codenameone web browser component input controls references?

Tags: codenameone

Does anybody know how can we get the form controls references in a web page that loaded in the CodeNameOne Web browser component?

I want to load a web page in CodeNameOne web browser component, then read or change the value of form input controls (For example TextBoxes) in the java code after pressing the submit button.

Regards,
Kasra

Answer (score 0):

Its not an ideal way to work and would reduce the portability of your application. You can look at the `JSObject` class that represents a bridge between the JavaScript and Java sides.